# Scala collections: spitting a list or URL in many lists grouped by domain

Tags: scala, collections

I'm trying to figure out what is the most convenient approach (meaning the most concise) to split a list of `URL`s ( `List[String]` ) in a `List[List[String]]` grouped by domain where every inner list contains `URL`s from the same domain, eg. www.somewhere.net

How would you face this task?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd probably do something like:

```
import java.net.URL
val urls = List("http://google.com/foo.html","http://google.com/bar.html","http://yahoo.com")

urls.groupBy{ case x => val url = new URL(x); url.getHost }.values
```

Comment: Even simpler, based on your solution : `urls.groupBy(new java.net.URL(_).getHost).values`

Comment: Additionally, the return type for the `values` call is `Iterable[List[String]]`. If you add `toList` at the end it will be the requested `List[List[String]]` type.